# d3 force graph zoom in and zoom out issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, force-layout

I have a d3 force graph, but i don't really know how i could zoom in and out.
Currently to zoom out, i am decreasing the circle radius by 5 and to zoom in i am increasing it by 5.
The problem is that i don't have an idea, of how to shrink or increase the text size with the circle.

**Link to jsFiddle:**

[http://jsfiddle.net/s5wfg7g6/2/](http://tinyurl.com/obwqp8b)

Code(HTML):

```
<input type="button" onClick="zoomIn();" value="Zoom In">
<input type="button" onClick="zoomOut();" value="Zoom Out">
<svg width="500" height="500" style="background-color: lightgrey; border: 1px solid black;">
</svg>
<script>
var r = 30;
function zoomIn()
{
    r += 5;
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("r", r);
}
function zoomOut()
{
    r -= 5;
    d3.selectAll("circle").attr("r", r);
}
</script>
```

Code(JS):

```
var nodes = [
    {
        "name": "node1",
        "group": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "subNode1",
        "group": "1"
    }
];
var links = [
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1
    }
];
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var color = d3.scale.category20();
var textXPlus = 31;
var textYPlus = 2;
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-160)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(150)
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "10px")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
var links = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.group); })
    .call(force.drag);
force.on("tick", function()
{
    links.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    nodes.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    texts.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x + textXPlus; })
    .attr("y", function(d){ return d.y + textYPlus; });     
});
```

Comment: Why are you not using the standard d3/svg zoom: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999?

Comment: The physics on the circles were stuttery with the regular zoom function.

Comment: But if you manage to get it working, please send me a jsfiddle link.

Comment: SO is not for fixing your issues. At the end you should use the integrated zooming as already said. Could you maybe also tell us what you want to have at the end? Here is an example of mine: http://arda-maps.org/familytree/ Do you want it to behave like that? It's a bit advanced but should help you to see if this would be what you want.